# matching observation from one data.table to headers in another data.table and returning the value

Tags: r, data.table

I was wondering if is there a function to match an observation in dataset 1 with the header in dataset 2 and returning a particular observation in dataset 2,

for example

```
v1<-1:4
v2<-5:8
data1<-as.data.table(cbind(v1,v2))
data1
colnames(data1)<-c("dog","cat")
data1
v3<-c("dog","cat")
v4<-c("tiger","lion")
data2<-as.data.table(cbind(v3,v4))
if (dat2[1,1]==colnames(data1)) { I would like to get the first observation 
in data1 under the column header dog}

desired output: 1
```

And i should get the value 1. Is there a function that can fit into { I would like to get the first observation in data1 under the column header dog} that returns that particular value?

Comment: You have two matrices there. How is it even related to `data.table`?

Comment: edited to convert the matrices to data.tables, i have a larger data table in my real sample, just wanted to create a simple reproducible example

Comment: Please include an object containing your desired output.

Comment: Ok. It should be no surprise that there is not a function for that. It is a very specific task (and, in my opinion, odd) task.

Comment: The best (silly) option I can think of is `data1[[data2[[1]][1]]][1]`

Answer (score 0):

This will return the first row of data1 for any column with a value anywhere in data2:

```
data1[1,.SDcols = names(data1)[data2 %in% names(data1)]]

  dog cat
1:   1   5
```